# Display multidimensional array in foreach loop

Tags: multidimensional-array

I'd like to display the multidimensional array in foreach loop.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `marvin`.`moje`;");
$i = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $sql[$i] = array($row['id'], $row['name'], $row['price'], $row['material']);
    $i++;
}
```

How to write the loop now for the multidimensional array `$sql[$i]`? I really want to use foreach loop. Don't write while loop please.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to simple change this while loop into foreach loop ?

Comment: No, I want to display the content of the array $sql[$i] with foreach loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be simple this:

```
foreach ($sql[$i] as $sqld) {
      echo $sqld;
    }
```

So the could should look like:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `marvin`.`moje`;");
$i = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $sql[$i] = array($row['id'], $row['name'], $row['price'], $row['material']);
    foreach ($sql[$i] as $sqld) {
      echo $sqld;
    }
    $i++;
}
```

And if you would like to display it outside while loop:

```
foreach ($sql as $sqli) {
    foreach ($sqli as $sqld) {
       echo $sqld;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not right. The script is not functional. White screen is displayed.

Comment: But I don't want it inside while loop.